# window.open auto break the for loops

Tags: javascript, html

I try to use window.open in my for-loop, such as:

```
[1,2,3].forEach(value => {
    window.open('https://stackoverflow.com')
});

for(var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    window.open('https://stackoverflow.com')
}
```

But for this code, browser will open the website only once. The for-loop seems auto break. How to fix it?

Comment: Executing your code opens 6 tabs for me. I allowed popups at some time for stackoverflow.

Comment: @RolandStarke which browser do you use? I am using Chrome.

Comment: you must have to `Allow popup` on for stackoverflow in order to open 3 of them.

Comment: Firefox, (but as Shailesh said, it only worked after i allowed them)

Comment: @RolandStarke Thanks. It works.